# variables not concatenating in BusyBox

Tags: bash, echo, concatenation, busybox

Following code puts the proper value in `$monthdata` and `$daydata` but when I try to print them out concatenated it does not work.

```
month05="AD"
day25="QGTKDO"

curmonth=$(date +"%m")
eval monthdata="\$month$curmonth"
curday=$(date +"%d")
eval daydata="\$day$curday"
c="$monthdata$daydata"

echo $c
```

This echo outputs "QGTKDO". If c="$daydata$monthdata" then the output is "ADTKDO", as if instead of concatenating it overlays them. I Am on BusyBox v1.23.1

Comment: Sounds like your script has DOS line-endings (so the strings do). Try running `dos2unix` or similar on it. Also see the [tag:bash] info page as this is one of the first suggestions on there.

Comment: You're the king! :) please post it as answer so i can mark it as accepted... i would have never found this not even after 2 months of searching

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`, and not `ash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your script has DOS line-endings (so the strings do). Try running dos2unix or similar on it. Also see the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) info page as this is one of the first suggestions on there. – Etan Reisner